# Add subview to selected tableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have this code as following. I am trying to add a subview with background color red to my selected tableView cell. But I am facing two bugs:

1: The height of the tableView Cell is 44, but when I set my subView's height to be 44, it seems to be half of the cell height. I can only make the two views equal when the subView frame height is set to be 88.

2: The subView only shows up when I tab it twice. If I tab it for only once, The sub View doesn't show up.

BTW: I have two tableViews in one viewController, so please look at the tableView inside of "else".

[image]

Comment: Instead of image add your code

Comment: Try to add the subview to seletectCell.contentView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in you code is that you try to add selectedBar view directly to selectedCell and this isn't valid you must add it to contentView of selectedCell

like this

```
  selectedCell.contentView.addSubview(selectedBar)
```

Also selectedBar is shown when you tap twice because you must add this to the end of didSelectRowAt

```
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
```

// Edit -> add tag of 555 when you create the view

add this code in cellForRowAt

```
if(index == indexpath.row)
{
      // add the view here 

}
else
{
   for i in 0..<selectedCell.contentView.subviews.count
   {
     let cv = selectedCell.contentView.subviews[i]

     if cv.tag == 555
     {
        cv.removeFromSuperview()
     }

   }

}
```

**Note:** when you select didSelectCellAt update only the index to indexpath.row

and reload the table

Comment: now the problem is I want the added subview to stay there until I selected another tableViewCell. The way I was doing is using a index number to mark my previous cell. By using the index number, I can remove the previous added subviews when I select another cell. But it doesn't work. Please help me with it. Thank you!  I used "willRemoveSubview"